# Swift 3 days between two dates

Tags: swift, date

```
    func setDate(){
    let start = "2016-04-18"
    let end = "2017-02-13"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: start)!
    let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: end)!

    let cal = NSCalendar.current

    let unit : Set<Calendar.Component> =  [.day]

    let daysBetween = cal.dateComponents(unit, from: startDate, to: endDate)

    dayText.text = "\(daysBetween)"
    print(daysBetween)

}
```

I have this code and my problem is i get the following text as a result:

> day: 301 isLeapMonth: false

I only want the number from that text.

Comment: Just print `daysBetween.day`.